# Use port in relative url

Tags: http, url, relative-path

Is there a way to specify i different port when getting data from a relative url?

example of relative urls:

```
~/path/page.html
../../path/page.html
```

What i would like to do is this:

```
:8012/path/page.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You'll have to include the host name as well (see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc3986.html#rfc.section.4.2.p.1).