# Changing swagger-ui server variable at runtime

Tags: swagger-ui

Using an openapi v3 configuration I have a server variable called 'hostname' that is used to build the url, like:

```
...
servers:
- url: http://{hostname}/api
 variables:
  hostname:
   "default": "some default here"
....
```

At runtime I'd like to be able to change the 'hostname' server variable. I've found the UI element on the page,

```
<input type="text" value="some default here" data-variable="hostname">
```

Changing the variable by editing the input field works fine, but changing the input field via jQuery isn't working, even when triggering the "change" event after setting the value, the value reverts when expanding one of the api sections. I also tried triggering the keyup/keydown and focusin/focusout events to better simulate how a user would change the field.

Is there a more swagger-ui approach to changing this value through an exposed call? I've looked through window.ui but its kind of cryptic.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to automate the testing of API calls?

Comment: I have an api.yaml file hosted on different IoT devices. Each device will have a different hostname based on its configuration. When the page is loaded I'm trying to use javascript to set the 'hostname' server variable to be window.location.hostname, for example via javascript.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I have an api.yaml file hosted on different IoT devices. Each device will have a different hostname based on its configuration. When the page is loaded I'm trying to use javascript to set the 'hostname' server variable to be window.location.hostname, for example via javascript.

You can simply specify a relative server `url` – it will be resolved relative to the location of the OpenAPI definition file.

For example, if you have

```
servers:
  - url: /api
```

and the API definition file is at

```
http://foobar/spec/api.yaml
```

then the base `url` for API calls will be resolved to

```
http://foobar/api
```

Comment: This is working well for the local server version. Is it possible to modify the url entries at runtime? I'm thinking of the case where I might want to let people plug in a dynamic url in one case but use this simplified relative path in another. I could of course use two different .yaml files but in my case the hosting page would know if it were on the embedded side vs. the other web case.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the use case, you can simply use `servers` with 2 items, `url: /api` and `url: http://{hostname}/api` (as in your original example), and let the user pick the one they want.

Comment: That's almost the use case. For the embedded side the relative /api works great, thanks! For the web side I may want to point all web users at a fake server endpoint like https://sometest.server.com. I guess I could put in that url to the yams file but I was hoping to be able to use the hosting page to do the setup without two .yaml files or two server entries to potentially confuse users. So the web host could run some js to set the server to https://simetest.server.com but the embedded side would keep the /api.

Comment: How do you add a port number to the url? Setting `:12345/api` results in sending request `/:12345/api/`

Comment: @user2233706 you can't have a [relative URL to a port number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26232210/113116) without a hostname. URLs with a port number MUST include the hostname, e.g. `- url: http://localhost:12345/api`. A possible workaround is to host your OpenAPI definition on the same port as the API itself, in this case you can specify just the path prefix without the hostname and port, i.e. `- url: /api`.

Answer (score 7):

You can alter the spec json before it render by writing a plugin

```js
const ui = SwaggerUI({
    // ...
    plugins: [
        // add a plugin to alter spec before it rendered
        {
            statePlugins: {
                spec: {
                    wrapActions: {
                        updateJsonSpec: function(oriAction, system) {
                            return (spec) => {
                                // change spec.servers here to add new entry, use concat to put it as the first & default one
                                spec.servers = [{url: someDynamicUrlInRuntime}].concat(spec.servers || [])
                                return oriAction(spec)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
    // ...
})
```

Comment: If the host and basePath are dynamic , only doing some modification in frontend works.

Answer (score 5):

Adapting the [answer from nevermind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51115593/changing-swagger-ui-server-variable-at-runtime/58464385#58464385) for use with SwaggerUIBundle as used in the [index.html from swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/17093f2c7c0b77376d3cd7124dc35969c54ee0c6/dist/index.html):

```js
plugins: [
  SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl,

  // Custom plugin that replaces the server list with the current url
  function() {
    return {
      statePlugins: {
        spec: {
          wrapActions: {
            updateJsonSpec: function(oriAction, system) {
              return (spec) => {
                    spec.servers = [{url: window.location.origin}]
                    return oriAction(spec)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
```

This way the index.html can be served from the backend service itself and will refer only on its own url.