# Dynamic change servers url

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I have web app that i deploy for multiple clients (lets say client1.com, client2.com and client3.com). I wrote REST API documentation using OA3 specification.

I have index.yaml which looks like:

```
openapi: 3.0.0

info:
  title: REST API
  description: REST API
  version: 0.0.1

servers:
  - url: http://client1.com/api
  description: Something ...

tags: ...
```

and standard Swagger-ui index.html

```
// Begin Swagger UI call region
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  url: "docs/index.yaml",
  dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
  deepLinking: true,
  presets: [
    SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
    SwaggerUIStandalonePreset.slice(1)
  ],
  plugins: [
    SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
  ],
  layout: "StandaloneLayout"
});
// End Swagger UI call region
window.ui = ui;
```

My problem is that i need to change servers.url depending on where and for which client i deploy app, so that each client can test API on his own servers and i don't want clients to see each other and know about each other in REST API docs.

How can i "dynamically" change / set server.url ? One "walkaround" solution is to copy index.yaml for each client and hardcode servers.url, but im sure there is better way which i don't see / know about.

Edit #1: given duplicate answer does not help because when i set servers to

```
servers: 
  - url: /api
```

swagger ui still points to `http://localhost:8080/api/` but my app url is `http://localhost:8080/myapp/`. I could set `servers: - url: /myapp/api` but this is hardcoded value in index.yaml and that does not work for me. I need like "configurable" server url.
But thanks anyway

Edit #2: my current walkaround solution is to process yaml with server side code. In index.yaml i have:

```
servers:
  - url: ##INSERT_SERVERS_TAG_HEREapi
```

and i replace `##INSERT_SERVERS_TAG_HERE` with `myapp.client.com/`. But i'm still looking for some better solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing swagger-ui server variable at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51115593/changing-swagger-ui-server-variable-at-runtime)